# How to run node js script from powershell script and use the output of node js script in powershell script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell

I have a node js script that can return a string value. I want to return that value and use it in PowerShell script.

I have done `console.log();` to print the output. How to use it in PowerShell script?
The output looks like this:

```
D:\development\js-automation>node index.js MyNewProject
MyNewProject
https://github.com/avadhvashisth/MyNewProject.git
```

Comment: In your code, save the output as a variable and then call the function with the variable as an argument, then run your code in the terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell can capture all the standard output to a string. Make sure you specify the path to your node.exe and include the file extension or Powershell will consider it a command:

```
$MyOutput = .\node.exe index.js MyNewProject
```

`$MyOutput` should contain everything returned by node